# How can I be notified of an index being updated on DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have a table (`key=username`, `value=male or female`) and an index on the values.

After I add an item to the table, I want to update the counts of males and females. **However, after a successful write, as the index is a Global Secondary Index, the count query is not consistent.**

Is there a way (dynamo db Streams, Lambda, ...) to monitor when the index is up to date?

Note that Im not looking for a solution that involves something else (keep count of increments in redis or ...), what I describe here is a simplified problem to especially ask a question about how can I monitor an index in dynamo.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a way to be notified of updates to an GSI. Therefore, you can't monitor when it is up to date.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if there is any mechanism currently provided to check this but, you can easily solve this problem by adding a single line of code to your query.

```
ConsistentRead = True
```

DynamoDB has a parameter when set as true will make sure that you get latest updated value.

Now, when you add/update the item and then query the data add ConsistentRead option in it, this will ensure that you will have latest count value.

Here is the reference [link.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)

If you are able to accomplish using other technique then please do share it.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This flag is ignored when reading from a GSI, as GSIs are eventually consistent.